# How to delete the back button of browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
      <div>
            <ul>
              <li id="News">News</li>
              <li id="Messages">Messages</li>
              <li id="Notifications">Notifications</li>
              <li id="Projects">Projects</li>
              <li id="AboutUS">About Us</li>
              <li id="LogOut">Log Out</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
```

script.js:

```
//Log Out from the application
$("#LogOut").click(function(){
    sessionStorage.removeItem('userName');
    sessionStorage.clear();
    window.location.assign("index.html");
  });
```

After being logged out and redirected to the page `index.html`, I clicked the back button of the browser and I was redirected to the last page. I found this [Disable browsers back button if the session is invalidated [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357394/disable-browsers-back-button-if-the-session-is-invalidated)
. I tried to add it in the index.html:

```
<body class="body" onload="noBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">            
        <form>

          <input id="login" type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter login">

          <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password">

          <div class="button_container">
            <button  id ="submit_button" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><label for="submit">Login</label></button>
          </div>
        </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script1.js"></script>
</body>
```

script1.js:

```
window.history.forward();
function noBack()
{
  window.history.forward();
}
```

But it doesn't work.How to unable a user to go to the previous page?

Comment: You don't.  The user can reload anything they want from history.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: On every page where you need to be logged in to visit, do a check to see if the user is logged in. Otherwise, redirect to login or index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible or a good idea.
I guess you just dont want the user to go back to the content after logout.
You could do something like this:

```
// To prevent undefined error
    if (localStorage.getItem("auth") == undefined) {
                localStorage.setItem("auth", false)
            }
// functionality
    $(document).ready(function(){
// when logout button is clicked
        $("#logout-btn").click(function(){
            localStorage.setItem("auth", false)
        });
// when auth is not true gets redirected back to the login page or index.html (maybe you could put in a preventDefault otherwise it could get stuck in a loop)
        if(localStorage.getItem("auth") == false){
            window.location.href = "index.html";
        }
    });
// on login set auth to true
```

hope you get the what i mean.
The best way to do it is on Server side with a session cookie.